# How to move a middle <p> in this image in flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

[image]

```css
.navtext {
  color: rgb(236, 234, 234);
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 20px;
}

.navbutton {
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 14px 28px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer
}

.navbutton:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: black;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <img class="navphoto" src="images/navphoto.jpg">
  <div class="navtext">
    <h2 class="navh2">Check out the newest collection of clothes</h2>
    <p class="pnavtext">High quality, fashionable clothes for all year around for men and women.</p>
    <button class="navbutton">Check it out</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

So I want to move the high quality `<p>` from the middle closer to check out `<h2>`. How do I do that? I wanted to separate text from button with a div inside `.nav` div but it's not working because it's still not separated.

Comment: You need to adjust the gap property of the container. Also if you want to bring it more closer, play around with the default margins of p and h2.

Comment: remove the gap property and manually adjust by giving margin-bottom to .navh2 or margin-top to .pnavtext.

Comment: @madlib reset the margin and padding by using universal selector then use gap and if you want more space between button and p tag then give it margin-top according to your need

Comment: The `<h2>` has default margins defined (as do h1,h3,h4,h5,h6 and p), you need to adjust the `h2 { bottom-margin }`, or set `margin: 0` and use `padding` with the spacing you want/need. `gap` only adds *extra* spacing when applicable...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `margin-top` on `.pnavtext` so it will move upward and also remove `gap` from `.navtext`. Look the following code:

```css
.navtext {
  background-color: black;
  color: rgb(236, 234, 234);
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30px 0px;
}

.pnavtext {
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.navbutton {
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 14px 28px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer
}

.navbutton:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: black;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <img class="navphoto" src="images/navphoto.jpg">
  <div class="navtext">
    <h2 class="navh2">Check out the newest collection of clothes</h2>
    <p class="pnavtext">High quality, fashionable clothes for all year around for men and women.</p>
    <button class="navbutton">Check it out</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `gap` from `.navtext` and you should get the desired result

```css
.navtext {
  background-color: black;
  color: rgb(236, 234, 234);
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.navbutton {
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 14px 28px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer
}

.navbutton:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: black;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <img class="navphoto" src="images/navphoto.jpg">
  <div class="navtext">
    <h2 class="navh2">Check out the newest collection of clothes</h2>
    <p class="pnavtext">High quality, fashionable clothes for all year around for men and women.</p>
    <button class="navbutton">Check it out</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Minimum two easy ways to do that:

1. Reduce gap propertey from `gap: 20px;` to maybe 10px;
2. Add margin-top: -20px; to your `.navbutton` class. See example below:

```css
.navtext {
  color: rgb(236, 234, 234);
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 20px;
}

.navbutton {
  margin-top: -20px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 14px 28px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer
}

.navbutton:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: black;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <img class="navphoto" src="https://...">
  <div class="navtext">
    <h2 class="navh2">Check out the newest collection of clothes</h2>
    <p class="pnavtext">High quality, fashionable clothes for all year around for men and women.</p>
    <button class="navbutton">Check it out</button>
  </div>
</div>
```